# In a DDD design, how to pass domain service through AR

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design

I have the following aggregate:

- Checkout (root)
- Requirement: CouponRequirement, AnotherRequirement, YetAnotherRequirement
- Coupon

A `Checkout` has many `Requirements` that need to be fulfilled in order for a `Checkout` to complete.
Each `Requirement` has a `fulfill(data)` method that is responsible for the fulfillment process.

One of those requirements is a `CouponRequirement` which, when fulfilled, needs to make sure there is stock for a particular coupon and reserve it.
For this to happen I need access to a `CouponRepository` or `CouponService`.

How could I tailor my design to accomodate that dependency?

FulfillRequirementCommand

```
function handle($cmd) {
   $cho = $this->checkoutRepository->get($cmd->checkoutId);
   $cho->fulfillRequirement($cmd->requirementType, $cmd->requirementData);
}
```

Checkout

```
function fulfillRequirement($reqType, $reqData) {
    $req = $this->getRequirement($reqType);
    $req->fulfill($reqData);
}
```

CouponRequirement

```
function fulfill($data) {
    // check stock / reserve coupon
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How could I tailor my design to accomodate that dependency?

The usual answer is that the application passes to the aggregate root any capabilities that are needed to perform its work.

In your particular case, this would probably look like an instance of a `CouponService` being passed to the Checkout aggregate root as an argument of the fullfillRequirement method.

> Maybe I just can't have a generic fulfillRequirement and need one for each concrete type?

I would expect that to be the case; after all you've already identified one use case where the paths are different.

Comment: That would seem the obvious answer, but `fulfillRequirement` can also fulfill a different type of requirement, like `ClientInformationRequirement` that needs a different dependency (or none).
Maybe I just can't have a generic `fulfillRequirement` and need one for each concrete type?
The other solution is to use a static service locator, which I would prefer not to.